# The name "MvxWindowsPage" does not exist in the namespace "using:Cirrious.MvvmCross.WindowsUWP.Views"

Tags: c#, xaml, mvvmcross, uwp

I am starting working with MVVMCross.
I had created the View and view model.
The View.xaml look like that:

```
<views:MvxWindowsPage
x:Class="xxx.Client.UWP.Views.View1"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
xmlns:views="using:Cirrious.MvvmCross.WindowsUWP.Views"
mc:Ignorable="d">
```

But I get this error:

```
The name "MvxWindowsPage" does not exist in the namespace "using:Cirrious.MvvmCross.WindowsUWP.Views"
```

But in my View.xaml.cs i had inherited from it without error:

```
    public sealed partial class View1 : Cirrious.MvvmCross.WindowsUWP.Views.MvxWindowsPage
```

Do you know what the problem is?

Thanks.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg405492(v=pandp.40).aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tested it with MvvmCross 4.0.0-beta3, and it works without any problem.

If you are using the correct version, see if you can repro the issue using the following steps. Just want to make sure we are doing the same thing.

1. In Visual Studio 2015 RTM-> new-> project-> c#-> windows-> universal-> Blank App(Universal Windows) name it "Test.Client.UWP".
2. Right click on the project node in VS solution explorer -> Manage NuGet Packages -> Check "include prerelease" and search mvvmcross -> Select the Latest prerelease 4.0.0-beta3 and install. (make sure there is no error in output window)
3. Add Views folder in the project root -> Add a blank page named View1 -> do the following changes:

Change to View1.xaml.cs

```
namespace Test.Client.UWP.Views
{
    /// <summary>
    /// An empty page that can be used on its own or navigated to within a Frame.
    /// </summary>
    public sealed partial class View1 : Cirrious.MvvmCross.WindowsUWP.Views.MvxWindowsPage
    {
        public View1()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

Change to View1.xaml

```
<views:MvxWindowsPage
    xmlns:views="using:Cirrious.MvvmCross.WindowsUWP.Views"
    x:Class="Test.Client.UWP.Views.View1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:Test.Client.UWP.Views"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">

    </Grid>
</views:MvxWindowsPage>
```

Comment: That worked.
I had not used the "Start pack" because it was not worked (Package installation fail) with my Core (ViewModel) project. What type of Project you suggest me for the Core project?

Comment: I Installed a portable class project and installed "MvvmCross.HotTuna.MvvmCrossLibraries 4.0.0-beta3" it seems working.